# javascript: check box value stays as 1 instead of 0 when unchecked

Tags: javascript, ajax, cordova

Hi am learning phonegap recently. I have this code below. My intention is to get user record from the mysql and then come out with some tick box where the user can update and then write directly in to the mysql.

The process is working fine, just the funny thing is that the value of the checkbox, even if I un-check it, it still stays as 1 instead of 0

Can please advice where I went wrong? FYI, I am new to javascript too, so likely it's just js error that is causing this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>PhoneGap Ajax Sample</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="phonegap.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function appReady(){
        var myId = sessionStorage.getItem('myId');

        var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
            ajax.open("GET","domain/system_setup.php?user_id="+myId+"",true);
            ajax.send();

        ajax.onreadystatechange=function(){
                if(ajax.readyState==4 && (ajax.status==200||ajax.status==0)){
                    eval('var data = ' + ajax.responseText + ';');
                    var theResults = data.dataset;
                    var theHtml = '';
                    for(var i=0;i<theResults.length;i++){
                    if (theResults[i].system_1 == 1) {
                        var theHtml = theHtml + '<input name="system_1" type="checkbox" id="system_1" value="1" checked="checked" />MS Excel';
                    } else {
                        var theHtml = theHtml + '<input name="system_1" type="checkbox" id="system_1" value="0" />MS Excel';
                    }   
                    if (theResults[i].system_2 == 1) {
                        var theHtml = theHtml + '<BR><input name="system_2" type="checkbox" id="system_2" value="1" checked="checked" />MYOB';
                    } else {
                        var theHtml = theHtml + '<BR><input name="system_2" type="checkbox" id="system_2" value="0" />MYOB';
                    }   
                    if (theResults[i].system_3 == 1) {
                        var theHtml = theHtml + '<BR><input name="system_3" type="checkbox" id="system_3" value="1" checked="checked" />Quickbooks';
                    } else {
                        var theHtml = theHtml + '<BR><input name="system_3" type="checkbox" id="system_3" value="0" />Quickbooks';
                    }
                    if (theResults[i].system_4 == 1) {
                        var theHtml = theHtml + '<BR><input name="system_4" type="checkbox" id="system_4" value="1" checked="checked" />Xero';
                    } else {
                        var theHtml = theHtml + '<BR><input name="system_4" type="checkbox" id="system_4" value="0" />Xero';
                    }                           
                    if (theResults[i].system_5 == 1) {
                        var theHtml = theHtml + '<BR><input name="system_5" type="checkbox" id="system_5" value="1" checked="checked" />SAP';
                    } else {
                        var theHtml = theHtml + '<BR><input name="system_5" type="checkbox" id="system_5" value="0" />SAP';
                    }   
                    if (theResults[i].system_6 == 1) {
                        var theHtml = theHtml + '<BR><input name="system_6" type="checkbox" id="system_6" value="1" checked="checked" />Navision';
                    } else {
                        var theHtml = theHtml + '<BR><input name="system_6" type="checkbox" id="system_6" value="0" />Navision';
                    }   
                    if (theResults[i].system_7 == 1) {
                        var theHtml = theHtml + '<BR><input name="system_7" type="checkbox" id="system_7" value="1" checked="checked" />Others';
                    } else {
                        var theHtml = theHtml + '<BR><input name="system_7" type="checkbox" id="system_7" value="0" />Others';
                    }                                                                               

                    }
                }   
        document.getElementById('main').innerHTML = theHtml;
        }
    }

    function updateSystem (form) {
        var system_1 = form.system_1.value;
        var system_2 = form.system_2.value;
        var system_3 = form.system_3.value;
        var system_4 = form.system_4.value;
        var system_5 = form.system_5.value;
        var system_6 = form.system_6.value;
        var system_7 = form.system_7.value;

        var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
            ajax.open("GET","domain/system_setup_update.php?user_id="+sessionStorage.getItem('myId')+"&system_1="+system_1+"&system_2="+system_2+"&system_3="+system_3+"&system_4="+system_4+"&system_5="+system_5+"&system_6="+system_6+"&system_7="+system_7+"",true);
            ajax.send();            

            ajax.onreadystatechange=function(){
                if(ajax.readyState==4 && (ajax.status==200||ajax.status==0)){
                    eval('var data = ' + ajax.responseText + ';');
                    var theResults = data.dataset;
                    for(var i=0;i<theResults.length;i++){   
                        var theRefresh = window.location = "system_setup.html";
                    }   
                    document.getElementById('refresh').innerHTML = theRefresh;          
                    }
                }
        }
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", appReady, false);

    </script>

    <style type="text/css">
        .line {padding-bottom:2px;}
        .title {float: left; width: 80px;}
        .content {margin-left: 90px; }
        .clear{clear:both;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>System Used</h1>

<FORM NAME="myform" ACTION="" METHOD="GET">
    <div id="main">
    </div>
<INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="button" Value="Update" onClick="updateSystem(this.form)">
</FORM>
    <div id="refresh">
    </div>  
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advanced!!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

gonchuki is correct you would need something like

```
var radio = document.getElementById('YOUR_RADIO_ID')

if (radio.checked)
{
    // do something here
}
```

Or in jQuery

```
$('#system_1 option:checked')
```

Would select whatever option is checked for `system_1`
But I'm pretty sure if you change

```
var system_1 = form.system_1.value;
var system_2 = form.system_2.value;
var system_3 = form.system_3.value;
var system_4 = form.system_4.value;
var system_5 = form.system_5.value;
var system_6 = form.system_6.value;
var system_7 = form.system_7.value;
```

To

```
var system_1 = form.system_1.checked;
var system_2 = form.system_2.checked;
var system_3 = form.system_3.checked;
var system_4 = form.system_4.checked;
var system_5 = form.system_5.checked;
var system_6 = form.system_6.checked;
var system_7 = form.system_7.checked;
```

your script should select the proper radio.

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Thanks!! This solved it! just changed the 'value' to 'checked' and it's solved!!

Answer (score 4):

you have to check againste the `checked` boolean property instead of the `value` of the item. In your use case, `value` has no real meaning, as it will remain with whatever you gave when created the markup and will not change no matter how many times you click on the checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you really want to have:

- one checkbox per item
- multiple checkboxes per item, so can tick 0 and 1 concurrently
- a radio button group to chose 0 or 1 per item

The code for the first solution would look like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="itemname" />

var result = form.itemname.checked ? "1" : "0";
```

The code for the third solution would look like that:

```
<input type="radio" name="itemname" value="1" /> Yes
<input type="radio" name="itemname" value="0" /> No

var buttons = form.itemname; // Array!
var result = false;
for (var i=0; i<buttons.length; i++)
    if (buttons[i].checked)
        result = buttons[i].value;
```

The code you've posted above is solution two, and it works like my second example: `forms.itemname` is an Array, but there might be multiple options checked.